# Launch EC2 instances with a Name

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that launches *n* EC2 instances. When launching, it tags them with `Env: {{ env }}` and `ManagedBy: Ansible`, but I'd also like to add a name with some semblance of meaning. For me, this is usually something with a format like `<env>-<purpose><number>` (e.g. `dev-web02` or `prd-db01`).

I'd really like Ansible to do that for me, if at all possible.

I currently have my playbook built out such that `{{ exact_count }}` instances are verified to exist using the `ec2` module. Created instances are then given a name tag using the `ec2_tag` module:

```
- name: Instances | Tag each new instance with a name
  ec2_tag:
    aws_access_key: "{{ awscli.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ awscli.secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    resource: "{{ item.1.id }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "{{ env_short }}-{{ 'ws%02d' | format(item.0) }}"
  with_indexed_items: webservers.instances
```

This works great, the first time it's ever run. The problem is that it iterates not across all of my instances, but only across those that may've been created during *this* run of the playbook.

Is there a better way to do this such that new instances are able to detect the sequence and continue it so that on a second run, for example, after I've changed `{{ exact_count }}` from 1 to 2, the server created by that second run will get a `Name` value of `dev-ws02`?

This may be a lot to ask of Ansible and there may be a good reason I haven't found an answer, but sometimes you get pleasantly surprised, so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empirically, I've figured out that using the `tagged_instances` property seems to work. This value appears to contain every server that matches the tags, not just any that were *just* created. At the moment, I can't remember whether the `ec2_tag` module simply won't overwrite a tag that already exists or if existing tags are updated, but the net result seems to be working out the way I'd like it to work out.

Here is my updated task:

```
- name: Instances | Tag each new instance with a name
  ec2_tag:
    aws_access_key: "{{ awscli.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ awscli.secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    resource: "{{ item.1.id }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      # e.g. dev-web03, prd-anz01
      Name: "{{ env_short }}-{{ server_type_abbrev }}{{ '%02d' | format(item.0) }}"
  with_indexed_items: ec2.tagged_instances
```